# Unit testing a function which consumes request from django rest api view

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure what's the proper way to test functions which are used inside views/permission classes.

This is the payload of my request:

```
{"name": "John"}
```

And this is the function I want to test:

```py
def get_name(request):
    return request.data['name']
```

This is the view that will be using the function:

```py
class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        name = get_name(request=request)
        return Response(status=200)
```

How should I create a fixture to test the `get_name` function? I've tried this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def request_fixture()
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    return factory.get(
        path='',
        data={"name": "John"},
        format='json')

def test_get_name(request_fixture):
    assert get_name(request=request_fixture) == "John"
```

But I'm getting an error:
`AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute data`.

One workaround seems to be decoding the `body` attribute:

```py
def get_name(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    return data['name']
```

But it doesn't feel like the right way to do this and I guess I'm missing something about the `WSGIRequest` class. Can someone explain to me how it should be tested? It would be great if I could use the same fixture to test the view too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the test fixture.  You aren't testing the whole view, just a helper function.  You can make a request-like object very easily by adding a property to a lambda:

```
def test_get_name():
    request = lambda: None
    request.data = {"name": "John"}
    assert get_name(request=request) == "John"
```

Comment: I've made this example as simple as possible, but imagine the request payload is a huge dict and there are other functions to be tested with the same payload - fixture is handy. Of course, I could use a `Mock`, but I would really like to test the function on a proper class. Isn't it possible?